# How do I share my Glue Catalog with another account via Lake Formation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog, aws-lake-formation

I have created the Glue table in my source account. I then went to Lake Formation and shared the table with the target account.

When I go to Lake Formation in my target account, I do not see the shared table. Based on the documentation here (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lake-formation/latest/dg/viewing-available-shared-resources.html), it should automatically appear.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

1. Go to Lake Formation in the source account and grant the External Account (target account) access to your database/table
2. In the target account, go to Resource Access Manager and approve the resource share request

At this point the database/table will show up in the Lake Formation console. If you want to query it from Athena/Spectrum, you need to:

3. Go to Lake Formation and Create Table via a Resource Link. The source should be the shared table.

Documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lake-formation/latest/dg/cross-account-read-data.html

Comment: I had been strugggling to figure out step 3 thank you very much. My org has already setup Step 2 so I did not have to do that. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @Melissa answer. If you are using a tag based access control, you don't need the Resource Access Manager(RAM) part. Basically assigning tags to the database and tables you want to share, and grant the external account permission access to the tags should work.

Please refer to AWS detailed [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lake-formation/latest/dg/access-control-cross-account.html) as this will give you a more comprehensive guide on how to set it up.